# Adding column to primary key removes uniqueness

Tags: sql, hive, impala, tpc

I have around 34 million rows, each with 23 columns in the `store_sales` table in the   [tpc-ds dataset](https://github.com/cloudera/impala-tpcds-kit) .

I have a `composite primary key` of columns `ss_item_sk` and `ss_ticket_number`.

Upon running the query `SELECT count(DISTINCT <primary key>) ..` I'm able to see that it outputs the total number of rows present in the table.

Now I add another column along with the `primary key`, namely `ss_sold_date_sk`.

After this, if I run the `count`query, I get **fewer** number of rows being printed than before. Can someone explain to me, via example, why this could happen?

**TL;DR**

When does adding a column to a composite primary key ever stop making it unique?

Comment: I would guess that the new column has `NULL` values and this throws off the `count(distinct)`.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes I'm sure. but as Gordon said, I just realized that my third column has null values which I didn't notice before.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, you're right. I just noticed that there are null values present. Thanks!

Comment: Primary keys aren't allowed to have null columns?

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes, you're correct. I was trying to find unique columns in order to set them as primary keys and was wondering why the `select count..` query was reducing the number after adding another column.

Comment: Please share the code your code

Answer (score 2):

#### Demo

```
create table mytable (c1 string,c2 string);
insert into mytable values ('A','A'),('B',null),('C',null);
```

---

```
select count(distinct c1) as count_distinct from mytable;

+----------------+
| count_distinct |
+----------------+
|              3 |
+----------------+
```

As Expected - 3 distinct values - 'A','B' and 'C'

---

```
select count(distinct concat(c1,c2)) as count_distinct from mytable;

+----------------+
| count_distinct |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
```

As expected. Why? - see next query

---

```
select c1,c2,concat(c1,c2) as concat_c1_c2 from mytable;

+----+------+--------------+
| c1 |  c2  | concat_c1_c2 |
+----+------+--------------+
| A  | A    | AA           |
| B  | NULL | NULL         |
| C  | NULL | NULL         |
+----+------+--------------+
```

Concatenation with NULL yields NULL

---

```
select count(distinct c1,c2) as count_distinct from mytable;

+----------------+
| count_distinct |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
```

**BUG!!**

---

Here is a work-around the bug:

```
select count(distinct struct(c1,c2)) as count_distinct from mytable;

+----------------+
| count_distinct |
+----------------+
|              3 |
+----------------+
```

Comment: IMHO it's working as documented: *COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])

Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values. *

Comment: @dnoeth - First of all I can change the documentation at this moment. :-) Second, the UDF documentation (cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF‌​) states "count(DISTINCT expr[, expr]) - Returns the number of rows for which the supplied expression(s) are unique and non-NULL.". It doesn't state, nor your quote, that **all** the expressions in a row should be non-NULL.

Comment: And most important - if `select distinct ...` treats the columns' combination as different so should `select count ( distinct ...)` - therefore bug

Comment: Standard SQL doesn't define `COUNT(DISTINCT )` on multiple columns, so a vendor can probably implement whatever suits him best :-)